# Near Protocol Unknown arguments

Tags: node.js, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, near-api-js

It might be a stupid question, but I am trying to learn how to work with Near Protocol in Near academy.

In chapter 6, you have a task to login to NEAR using CLI, register yourself as a meme museum contributor and register your meme.

Link to the Chapter 6: https://near.academy/near101/chapter-6

**I have an issue when I try to register the meme. I am getting an error:**

*Unknown argument: {meme : bingoo, title : telephonememe, data : https://9gag.com/gag/a718nWb, category : 4}*

I am not sure why those arguments are percevied as unknown.

**Here's the code:**

near call museum.testnet add_meme \ '{"meme" : "bingoo", "title" : "telephonememe", "data" : "https://9gag.com/gag/a718nWb", "category" : 4}' --accountId bingoo.testnet --amount 4

Comment: I tried your command and it seemed to work; I got a different but (I think) expected error:  `This method can only be called by a museum contributor or owner`.

Maybe the terminal you are using is not parsing quotes or back-slashes properly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It must be something with my terminal. 
You get this error Marcelo because you need to enter this line, which adds you as a museum contributor:
near call museum.testnet add_myself_as_contributor --accountId YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME.testnet

Should I use different terminal or update it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a windows machine, and I was getting the same error.

I tried a bunch of things and I saw this AWS post on host to use quotes in the aws cli: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-quoting-strings.html

I think for windows you can't use the single quotes around the json object, and you can't do the \ for the newline. I would just one long string and \ the " inside the json. like this:

```
near call museum.testnet add_meme "{\"meme\" : \"bingoo\", \"title\" : \"telephonememe\", \"data\" : \"https://9gag.com/gag/a718nWb\", \"category\" : 4}" --accountId bingoo.testnet --amount 4
```

I think this is why they recommend using wsl for windows in their github repo:
Windows
For Windows users, we recommend using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

```
Install WSL 
Install npm 
Install Node.js 
Change npm default directory 
This is to avoid any permission issues with WSL
Open WSL and install near-cli globally by running:
npm install -g near-cli
```